# US mobile input field auto brackets and auto dash settings issue

Tags: javascript, jquery

**US mobile input field auto brackets and auto dash settings issue**

working for format "(XXX) XXX-XXXX"

My Code Snippet:

```js
      $("#contact_no").keyup(function() {
          var curchr = this.value.length;
          var curval = $(this).val();
          if (curchr == 3) {
              $(this).val("(" + curval + ")" + " ");
          } else if (curchr == 9) {
              $(this).val(curval + "-");
          }
      });
    </script
```

```html
 <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="text" class="form-control" name="contact_no" id="contact_no" placeholder="Contact Number">
```

above code working good, but **when we edit any in between digit/number then double brackets and double slashes arises**.

please suggest me changes for proper us-auto mobile format (auto brackets & slashesh)

Answer (score 0):

Try to think this way.
It's not complete as it still has issues with editing but I believe with a little effort you'll achieve your goal.

```js
$("#contact_no").keyup(function() {
  let matches = this.value.match(/\d+/g);
  if (!matches || matches.lenght == 0) {
    return;
  }

  let result = '';

  let inputCode = matches[0];
  if (inputCode.length < 3 && matches.length === 1) {
    result = inputCode;
  } else {
    result += '(' + inputCode.substring(0, 3) + ')';

    if (matches.length > 1) {
      let inputNumber = matches[1];

        result += ' ';
        result += inputNumber.substring(0, 3);

        if (matches.length == 2 && inputNumber.length > 3) {
          result += '-';
          result += inputNumber.substring(3, 4);
        }
    }
            
    if (matches.length > 2) {
      let inputNumber = matches[2];

      result += '-';
      result += inputNumber.substring(0, 4);
    }
  }

  $(this).val(result);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="text" class="form-control" name="contact_no" id="contact_no" placeholder="Contact Number">
```